# Convert SQL Query to WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I have been working with a third party wishlist module that causes some issues. Overcoming many of them I have one left.

The architecture of everything in our website is this:

- 12 Products
- 1 Random Category

The above loops with infinite scroll paging until the last page.

So, to achieve this I am using WP_Query.

However the plugin I am working on for the wishlist display page has the following query.

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT
                b.ID AS posts_id,
                b.post_title AS posts_title,
                b.post_content AS posts_content,
                b.post_date AS posts_date,
                c.ID AS authors_id,
                c.display_name AS authors_name
            FROM '.$var_setting['table'].' a
            LEFT JOIN '.$var_setting['table_posts'].' b
            ON a.item_id = b.ID
            LEFT JOIN '.$var_setting['table_users']." c
            ON c.ID = b.post_author
            WHERE
                b.post_status = 'publish'
                AND a.user_id = %s
            ORDER BY b.post_title DESC",
        $user_id
    )
);
```

Any ideas on how I could convert this to WP_Query, able to take args ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish with this SQL code?

Comment: The plugin tries to fetch the user's favorite posts (gadgets if you want the post type slug). It does so but I cannot work at all with a simple SQL Query. I would ideally like to pass the above to a new WP_Query.

Comment: Is the favorite status tracked in the post itself?

Comment: As you may see from the query above, there is a table storing the user id accompanied with the post id.

Comment: I don't know SQL that well. But off the top of my head if you can get at the post IDs of these favorites from a function, you can then feed it into a WP_Query using the `'post__in'` argument.

Comment: Sounds like a decent plan. Will try and post the results! Thank you.